# Why is the first method working but second isn't?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

**First Method:**

```
const getWeatherIcon = (iconParameter) => {
   const icon = `https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${iconParameter}@2x.png`
   return <img src={icon} alt={iconParameter} />
  }
```

---

```
<div className="weathericon">
       {getWeatherIcon(weather.weather[0].icon)} //Ex: weather.weather[0].icon=50n
</div>
```

**Second Method:**

```
const getWeatherIcon = (iconParameter) => {
    const icon = `assets/weather/${iconParameter}.svg`
    return <img src={icon} alt={iconParameter} />
  }
```

---

```
<div className="weathericon">
     {getWeatherIcon(weather.weather[0].main)} //Ex: weather.weather[0].main=Haze
</div>
```

**Here Is My Project Directory**

```
src
│   App.js
│   index.css
│   index.js   
│
└───assets
    └───weather
    |  |    Haze.svg 
    │  |    Clear.svg
    │  |    Rain.svg
    |  
    └───bg
        |   file111.png
        |   file112.png
```

**Ignore following**

*It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.*

Comment: Webpack doesn't know about your **assests** folder, because it's not imported. The browser will try to look for the `/assets/weather/<your>.svg` relative to the web "root", and it won't be there. If these are "static" assets you can put them under the **public** folder instead of **src**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This Worked!!**

```
const getWeatherIcon = (iconParameter) => {
    const icon = `${iconParameter}.svg`
    return < img src={icon} alt={iconParameter} width='100px' />
  }
```

---

```
<div className="weathericon">
                  {getWeatherIcon(weather.weather[0].main)}//Haze, Clear etc.
                </div>
```

---

**File System:**

```
src
│   App.js
│   index.css
│   index.js   
│
└───assets
│   └───bg
│   |   file111.png
│   |   file112.png
│
│        
public
│   Clear.svg
│   Clouds.svg
│   Rain.svg
│   Haze.svg
```

Answer (score 0):

You file path is not correct try to use ./assets/weather to give proper path